# Java regular expression with groups

Tags: java, regex, regular-language

I would like to replace all occurences of strings like:

```
"{something1}
"{someother2}
"{thing3}
```

but how to deal with group that contains string, not chars?

--
edit:

e.g. given String:

```
sometext "{something1}hello
```

I would like to have

```
sometext hello
```

or better, but its only replaceAll parameter

```
sometext "hello
```

Comment: What do you mean by "string, not chars"?

Comment: i know how to use patterns like this:
String pattern="[abc]" - this group contains chars. But I would like to make group of strings, not chars

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to achive by this. What kind of Strings do you want to match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can use [replaceAll](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

```
String b = a.replaceAll("\\{.*?\\}", "sometext ");
```

This will replace all characters surrounded by curly braces with the replacement string.

Comment: thank you for advice. I have completely forgot that String are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

Just build a regular expression using the `|` operator inside a group.

Comment: nor this:
        String pattern = "\"(\\{String\\}|\\{Long\\}|\\{Boolean\\}|\\{Number\\})";
nor this:
        String pattern = "\"({String}|{Long}|{Boolean}|{Number})";
have worked

Answer (score 1):

You could use the or '|' operator to match full strings  -

```
subject.replace(/something1|someother2|thing3/g, ",");
```